# SQL Recursive Query | multiple Tables Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, express, join, inner-join

**Scenario**

I have a few tables, each table represents an entity of a unique type. For example lets go with:

School, Subject, Class, Teacher. Listed in order as Parent -> Child

**Schema**

Each table has:

```
ID: UUID
Name: CHAR VARYING
{parent}_id: UUID<-- example, class would have Subject_id, or Teacher would have Class_id.
```

The `{parent}_id` is the foreign id for each table.

**Problem**

I want to make a query that lists all the teachers of a given school. In order to do this in this Schema, I need to first query Subject by `School_id`, then Class by `subject_id` and then finally teacher by `class_id`.

A recursive functions makes sense to me but all tutorials I find are doing this within a single table and by ids which don't change with each recursion. In my example, each recursion I will need to search for a different ID.

**Question**

How do you go about doing this? I could make an array of the ids and make an index, increase index and use that to access the id in the array. This however seems like a common query so I believe there might be a more elegant solution.

**Note**: I am using PostgreSQL

**Edit for Comment**

1. I am using PostgreSQL DB and PGAdmin
2. Why would UUID not work? It has worked up to this point with no problems; even works with cascading delete using foreign keys.
3. I can show actual schema. However here is a fictitious layout. Quite straight forward I hope.

| School |
| --- |
| ID |
| Name |

| Subject |
| --- |
| ID |
| Name |
| School_ID |

| Class |
| --- |
| ID |
| Name |
| Subject_ID |

| Teacher |
| --- |
| ID |
| Name |
| Class_ID |

Expected output

```
Teacher_ID, Teacher_Name, Class_Name, Subject_Name, School_Name
```

Comment: 1) You are using Postgres or Postgresql not PostGres. 2) `UUID` as `id`(presumably a PK) means an index on it will not work as well. 3) To question add complete table definitions and example of expected output.

Comment: added in the info, hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: I didn't say `UUID` would not work just that is inefficient when indexed which you want to do the make the FK look ups quicker.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver's answer which uses inner joins is the correct approach. Recursive SQL is something different and is not necessary to produce the results you want here.

Answer (score 1):

Something like?:

```
select 
   Teacher_ID, Teacher_Name, Class_Name, Subject_Name, School_Name
from 
   school
join 
   subject 
on
   school.id = subject.school_id
join
    class
on 
   class.subject_id = subject.id
join
   teacher
on 
    teacher.class_id = class.id
```